# jclouds filesystem example

Tags: java, jclouds

I am trying to test this example http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/filesystem/ but I get this error on the line:

```
BlobStoreContext context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("filesystem")
                 .overrides(properties)
                 .buildView(BlobStoreContext.class);
```

error:

```
13:39:23 ERROR main step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing the step
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/TypeAdapter
    at org.jclouds.rest.config.RestModule.configure(RestModule.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:59)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:403)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildInjector(ContextBuilder.java:327)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:618)
    at org.jclouds.ContextBuilder.buildView(ContextBuilder.java:598)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml or other build script?  Java complains about a missing Gson dependency in your example.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HWVKuuKh

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your Guava from 14.0 to 15.0 to match the jclouds dependency on Guava.  Do not  use a newer version than 15.0 since jclouds 1.7.x works around an incompatibility between Java 7u51 and Guava < 16.0.1 and the workaround does not support newer Guava:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-427

Comment: Thanks, I solved with this:

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez If this answer helped you, can you please validate it as a solution? It helps the community. Thanks